# Apparently the photoresistors don't pass the input at the leds

Tags: arduino-uno, led, photoresistor

I am making a school project where i need to create a parking loot in tinkercad. Me and my mate tried to use a bunch of photoresistor that worked as a sensor. No light = car = red led; light = no car = green led. We can't figure out why the leds dont turn on. We are still on a low level of abilities on this type of work and in class we didn't see a lot of components, so the photoresistor were one of the best choice.

Here is the screenshot of the whole project, it's in italian so if you guys needs a transduction of the variable just tell me. Don't mind the button, we were trying something.

[image]

Here is the code: In this line "if(analogRead(fotoresistori[i]) < 300)" we put 300 because with 0 etc. it did not work

```
int fotoresistori[] = {A0, A1, A2, A3, A4};
int verdi[] = {11, 10, 9, 8, 7};
int rossi[] = {6, 5 , 4, 3, 2};

void setup()
{
  pinMode(13, INPUT);
  pinMode(12, INPUT);
  pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.println(postiDisponibili);
  if(digitalRead(13) == HIGH){
    postiDisponibili++;
  }
  else if(digitalRead(12) ){
    postiDisponibili--;
  }
  for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
    if(analogRead(fotoresistori[i]) < 300){
      digitalWrite(rossi[i], HIGH);
      digitalWrite(verdi[i], LOW);
    }else{
      digitalWrite(rossi[i], LOW);
      digitalWrite(verdi[i], HIGH);
    }      
  }
  delay(500);
}
```

The value of A0 is always at 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not applying any voltage to the photoresistors and the other end is connected to earth so it will always be zero. You need to connect the analog end to +5v via a suitable current limiting resistor (suggest 10K for a typical photoresistor) then measure the voltage.

Comment: Ok thank you. I will try it now

Comment: I did this: https://i.imgur.com/gVTMa8A.png but the led still won't turn on. But thanks to you now the output of A0 is no longer stucked on 0.

Comment: Ok mate i did everything and i worked! At the end there was another error, but thanks for the advice

Comment: Glad you worked it out in the end